# how to add rrule to icalendar event in python?

Tags: python, icalendar

I am trying to create simple recurring events in Python with icalendar

```
from icalendar import Event
from datetime import datetime
ev = Event()
ev.add('dtstart', datetime(2013,11,22,8))
ev.add('dtend', datetime(2013,11,22,12))
ev.add('rrule', 'freq=daily')
```

I have got this exception : `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required` on the last line (the one with 'rrule')

Any thoughts ? I checked the ical doc but they don't have many python examples

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at `src/icalendar/tests/test_timezoned.py`:

```
 tzs.add('rrule', {'freq': 'yearly', 'bymonth': 10, 'byday': '-1su'})
 # event.add('rrule', u'FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=10)
```

So they must have changed their format to a dictionary instead

```
ev.add('rrule', {'freq': 'daily'})
```

works